# Issue with Round function in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a issue in SSRS when I use expression to use Round function

I need get the value Round down but always is up

I've the following expresion  3 - (4 *.32)  = 1.72 using a round(3 - (4 *.32)) always I get 2 but I need get 1

What I 'm using in a bad way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just need to get a whole number try casting to int it should always round up to the nearest whole number other use Math.Round()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa340227(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

round(3 - (4 *.32),0,1) will round to 0 decimal places, the 1 indicates rounding down.  You could also do the quick and dirty cast to int which will always take the floor.

Comment: I'm using the expression Round(Fields!NoNFF.Value - (Fields!NoSTUSwapped.Value * 0.32), 0, 1) but I got the error Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Round' can be called without a narrowing conversion....   What is missing!!!

Comment: Doesn't know the type of Fields!NoNFF.Value, you need to cast the expression "Fields!NoNFF.Value - (Fields!NoSTUSwapped.Value * 0.32)", maybe with Decimal.Round(CDec(Fields!NoNFF.Value - (Fields!NoSTUSwapped.Value * 0.32)), 0,1)

Comment: this is still no getting my want result..  I explain again...  if my value is 3 - (4 *.32) = 1.72 I want to show the value 1. without decimal values...   I thought to use round but maybe I'm wrong and there are other function or way to get my result

Answer (score 0):

`Int(3 - (4 *.32))` Will give you `1`.

Making it an `int` will always "round down", it's quick and easy, but not the best solution necessarily.