# SSRS Round to whole number

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In SSRS expression i need to round any number after division to whole minor number:

I mean: Round(2.2) = 2; ROUND(2.5) = 2; ROUND(2.8) = 2

There is any option to Round function to achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527561/issue-with-round-function-in-ssrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Fix` function will do this, it returns the integer portion of the number. eg

```
Fix(2.2)
```

which will return 2, or

```
Fix(2.7)
```

which will also return 2.

Comment: Thanks. It reolved my problem